# Python constant values not detected

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use sphinx cross-referencing and intersphinx to document my code. I can easily make hyperlinks to other docs, but Python should be included in core, and its constant values are not detected (`True`, `False` and `None`).

I imported interspinx and I have this in my mapping

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3.6", None),
    "discord": ("https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/", None),
}
```

I can make a reference to discord by doing this

```
:class:`discord.Guild
```

I can also reference Python docs, like that

```
:py:class:`str`
```

However, if I try to reference `True` or `False`, it's not working. I'm doing this

```
:py:const:`True`
```

But the text is not a hyperlink...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these will render the link.

```
:py:obj:`True`

:any:`True`
```

Comment: also ``:py:data:`True` ``

Comment: Can you provide an explanation why this works? I am having a hard time understanding what the [documentation ](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html?highlight=obj#role-py-obj) means by "Reference an object of unspecified type. Useful e.g. as the default_role"

Comment: I understand the default role part, but don't understand why using it as a domain works for linking to True.

My best guess is that everything in Python is an object so :obj: will get you anywhere you need to go?

Comment: Pretty much. If you do not know the type of object you are documenting (class, method, data, function, etc.), then `obj` is a good catch all type. `any` is similar in the reST context instead of Python domain.